# Сортировка словаря по значениям

Tags: python

У меня есть словарь (это чисто для пример, в самой программе роботов больше)

```
robots = {'robot1': [3, 0], 'robot2':  [3, 1], "robot3": [5, 2]}
```

Ключ это имя робота, а значения это его координаты в виде [x, y]. У меня в программе роботы получают точку (например [10, 10]) куда надо им надо двигаться, но двигаться им надо группой, лидером группы становится робот наиболее близкий к точке, за лидером следует второй по близости, а за вторым третий и т.д. В общем, я так понимаю, что мне нужна функция, которая вернёт мне словарь примерно такого вида:

```
robots = {'robot1': 3, 'robot2':  2, "robot3": 2 }
```

Где 1, 2 и 3 это номера роботов в группе.

Или так (point это означает,что робот должен идти к точке)

```
robots = {'robot1': "robot2" , 'robot2':  "robot1", "robot3": "point" }
```

Или так

```
robots = {'robot3': [5, 2], 'robot2': [3, 1], "robot1": [3, 0] }
```

Но мне больше нравится первый вариант и второй, так как роботу просто достаточно обратиться к словарю, чтобы узнать за кем ему следовать.

Вопросы:

1. Как сортируются словаря? Есть какие-то уже готовые методы для моего случая?
2. Есть какие-то другие более удобные варианты? Может в моё случае можно не использовать словарь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Словари в Python - `неупорядоченные` коллекции произвольных объектов с доступом по ключу.

Сортировка словаря по значениям:

```
robots = {'robot1': [3, 0], 'robot2':  [3, 2], "robot3": [5, 2], 'robot4': [3, 1],}
ss = sorted(robots.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1], reverse=True)

print(ss)
[('robot3', [5, 2]), ('robot2', [3, 2]), ('robot4', [3, 1]), ('robot1', [3, 0])]

type(ss)
<class 'list'>
```

Дальше, я так понимаю, вам надо обработать список `ss`

Comment: Спасибо. Сделал вот так

      ss = sorted(robots.items(), key=lambda item: (item[1][0] - point.x) ** 2 + (item[1][1] - point.y) ** 2)